# Cannot add android platform to meteor project

Tags: cordova, meteor

When I try to add the Android platform to my meteor project as

```
meteor add-platform android
```

I get the following error:

```
   While adding platform Android to Cordova project:
   Error: /Users/lucanaterop/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/4.1.1/package/bin/create:
   Command failed with exit code 8 Error output:

   /Users/lucanaterop/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/4.1.1/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
   throw e;
   ^
   Package name must look like: com.company.Name
   at ChildProcess.whenDone
   (/Users/lucanaterop/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.9.1gi495u++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:139:23)
   at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
   at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
   at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:979:11)
   at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
   at Pipe.close (net.js:466:12)
```

I am using latest version of meteor (1.2.0.2) on OS X El Capitan. I installed the Android SDK via Android Studio, as suggested by the meteor docs. Reinstallation of the whole Android SDK did not help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Google: [meteor add-platform android](https://www.google.com/search?q=meteor+add-platform+android) -- Tutorial [Running your app on Android or iOS](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/running-on-mobile)

Comment: The only step that I am supposed to do before said command is to install the android sdk. I did that, of course.

Comment: @Puegget, to be honest, I may not know how to fix this. However, you have neglected a few important points. What system are you using? Windows, OSX, Linux? Windows is the most troublesome, mostly because the following started late. So there is not a lot of information. However, I expect in the next few weeks things will change. Which system are you using?

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 Absolutely, sorry for that!! I am using latest version of meteor (1.2.0.2) on OS X El Capitan. I installed the Android SDK via Android Studio, as suggested by the meteor docs. Reinstallation of the whole Android SDK did not help.

Comment: Okay. Please put that information in your original post, so that other that read this may know if this question is helpful to them. I'll formulate an answer in the meantime. I'll assume you can add your info to the original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem with Meteor 1.2.1 on OS X Yosemite. My project was in a weird state somehow. Try resetting your project:

```
meteor reset
```