# meteor add-platform android: Errors executing Cordova commands:

Tags: meteor

Does anybody know why I am getting this when trying to add android platform in my meteor project?

```
>meteor add-platform android
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:

   While adding platform Android to Cordova project:
   Error validating package name. Package name must look like: com.company.Name
   at validatePackageName
   (C:\Users\gatsu\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\5.1.1\package\bin\lib\create.js:164:25)
   at Object.exports.create
   (C:\Users\gatsu\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\5.1.1\package\bin\lib\create.js:237:12)
   at Api.createPlatform
   (C:\Users\gatsu\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\5.1.1\package\bin\templates\cordova\Api.js:95:6)
   at
   C:\Users\gatsu\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.2_4\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\platform.js:191:24
   at _fulfilled
   (C:\Users\gatsu\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.2_4\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
   at self.promiseDispatch.done
   (C:\Users\gatsu\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.2_4\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
   at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch
   (C:\Users\gatsu\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.2_4\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\q\q.js:749:13)
   at
   C:\Users\gatsu\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.2_4\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\q\q.js:557:44
   at flush
   (C:\Users\gatsu\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.2_4\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
   at process._tickCallback (node.js:458:13)
```

I'm running windows 10 and METEOR@1.3.2.4 but the same message appears using osx.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Meteor on Windows does not support mobile builds.

You can read this in tutorials as well [here](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/running-on-mobile).

Comment: but the same message appears using osx

Comment: and im not really building for mobile by adding the android platform, I dont think

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
meteor reset
```

and see if that works for you.

(From https://stackoverflow.com/a/34299553/1756909)